# Links to Jquery UI accordion on the same page

Tags: jquery, user-interface, hyperlink, accordion

I am trying to create links on the same page as an accordion that will open the appropriate section and bring it to the top of the page. I am initializing the according via the code below and using the default set up for the accordion.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
autoHeight: false,
collapsible: true,
navigation: true,
active: false
});
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's not enough information to help, gernhart. If you could attach a description of what your problem is, along with the html of your links, it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you asking for something similar to a remote control, where you click on it and it opens a predefined section of the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Using the following you can target specific areas of an accordion to open. `active: 1` is the area you want to open.

(Note: The count starts from 0 if I remember correctly, so in this case your second area within the accordion will open!)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });
```

If you wanted to trigger this from clicking on a link somewhere on the same page, you could do something like the following

**The jQuery**

```
$("#exampleLink").click(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: 1 });  
    //remove return false; if you want it to jump to the top of the page when clicked
    return false; 
});
```

**The HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="exampleLink">Link Text</a>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Marc! The code above will open the accordion but doesn't bring the open section to the top of the page. I removed the "return false;" section and still didn't have any luck.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'bring it to the top of the page'... Do you mean to the top of the accordion? Have you got a link to the page available? Or a version of it on JSFiddle.net?

Comment: I am hoping to get the accordion header or content area that is active after the link has been clicked to be at the very top of the page like an anchor link when it has been clicked. Unfortunately the site that I am developing is offline at the moment.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle version of what I am working with. What i would like to happen is when you click the "Open 2nd Panel" link, the 2nd accordion panel opens and that panel is then moved to the top of the page the same way an anchor link would.

http://jsfiddle.net/RP8LB/